# C++ popen not returning right output after boot

Tags: c++, linux, service, popen

There is something weird when executing `popen` on Linux. So basically in a much bigger application I have a function called `execute` that runs a command by using `popen` and returns its stdout output.

```
#define CMD "some_command -s"     // This is the command
#define MAX_BUF 1024*6

static std::string execute(const char* cmd) {
        std::string result;
        char buffer[MAX_BUF];

        FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
        if(!pipe)
                throw -1;

        try{
                while(!feof(pipe)){
                        if(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUF, pipe) != NULL)
                                result += buffer;
                }
        }catch(...){
                pclose(pipe);
                throw;
        }

        pclose(pipe);
        return result;
}
```

This usually works fine, the problem comes when rebooting the system. If the applications runs as a daemon for a service, if this service is run at boot time the size of the `result` variable is `0`. When doing a `service name_of_service restart`, which kills and relaunches the application, then it works and the `result` variable size is the expected one.

Also tried executing `system("some_command -s > /tmp/command_out");` before running the `popen` and the file `/tmp/command_out` had the expected output. So this is not a race condition in which the `some_command` dependencies have not been initialized.

*UPDATE*

Running the command on another terminal at the same time also works. And inside the service, If I change `some_command -s` for other commands like `ls /tmp`, then popen does result in some output.

Comment: Read this:  [**Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I should fix it. But still I'm getting the same behavior as before.

Comment: What about stderr, and the process’s exit status?  And what (kind of) command is it?